# Intern path error in browser client

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

I have a conventional recommended Intern directory structure:

`MyProject
├── node_modules
│   ├── intern-geezer
│   │   ├── client.html
├── src
│   ├── myFunction.js
├── tests
│   ├── intern.js
│   ├── unit
│   │   ├── ps.js`

with a very simple config:

```
useLoader: {
    'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
    'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
},

loader: {
    packages: []
},

suites: [ 'tests/unit/ps' ]
```

and tests:

```
define(function (require) {
    var tdd = require('intern!tdd');

    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert'); 

    // Global function to test, not an AMD module
    var parseF = require('src/myFunction.js');

    var he = require('tests/he');

    tdd.suite('My tests', function() {
       //etc
   });
});
```

````

but when I open the browser client the loader is looking for the test suite inside the intern-geezer directory:

[image]

I am not setting a `baseUrl` in the config (or in the browser URL). I didn't have this trouble going through the regular (non-geezer) intern tutorial. Since the `baseUrl` defaults to two directories up from `client.html` I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help. (Yes, I will need geezer for ancient IE. No, I do not want to rewrite the function I'm testing as an AMD module.)

Answer (score 0):

The Intern loader doesn't know how to get to your tests because they haven't been registered as a package. When using the recommended directory structure, you'll want to also set up the recommended [loader configuration](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#common-config) so that Intern knows where to find your code and tests.

```
  loader: {
    packages: [
      { name: 'app', location: 'src/' },
      { name: 'tests', location: 'tests/' }
    ]
  }
```

Then, update your tests to correctly find the code you need to test.

```
    // Global function to test, not an AMD module
    var parseF = require('app/myFunction.js');
```

Now, Intern should be able to correctly find the code and tests.

Comment: Yeah, I started with that. Tried it again now. Doesn't work. With that code, client.html is looking for "node_modules/intern-geezer/app/myFunction.js" and not finding it. Seems like Intern is really designed around the assumption of AMD everywhere. The only way I can seem to point to the file is to hardcode the path in the unit test with "require('../../src/myFunction.js');" which works but seems totally wrong.

Comment: Can you show what you tried? I reproduced with the [intern-tutorial](https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial) and couldn't until I changed `loader.packages` to `[]`